# UI is crashing upon receiving push notifications when app is in foreground in flutter-Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, localnotification

I am using FCM. I am trying to show notification when my app is in foreground.
I am recieving notification successfully but app is crashing upon receiving it.

```
void initState() {

//TODO: Local notifications configuration.
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('notification_icon');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid,initializationSettingsIOS);

Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
  print('Showing alert');
  showDialog(context: context,builder: (_)=>AlertDialog(title: Text("Title"),));
}



FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

```
Future showNotifications() async {
  print('show');
  var androidPlatformSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails('123','Channel Name','Description about the channel',importance: Importance.Max,priority: Priority.Default);
  var iOSPlatformSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(androidPlatformSpecifics,iOSPlatformSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, 'New Post', 'Notification', platformChannelSpecifics);
  print('show');


}

//TODO:Configuration of firebase
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String,dynamic> message){
    debugPrint('on');
    showNotifications();
    print(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String,dynamic> message){
    debugPrint('resume');
    print(message);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String,dynamic> message){
    debugPrint('Launch');
    print(message);
  },

);

_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
  print(token);
});
```

After push notification I keep getting "System UI has stopped"